# Change content of specific file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple css files like bootstrap, normalize and custom.
When I try to change the background image by jquery, it inserts the css value in bootstrap.css rather than my custom css.

Is there any way to select a specific file where jquery can make changes?

My css load order is:
1 bootstrap.css
2 normalize.css
3 my own custon css

Thanks

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but *you need to help yourself first*. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Styles added with jQuery will be inline. This will take a higher precedence than any external stylesheets.

It sounds like you probably have the CSS loading in the right order. What should happen is the browser will apply styles from Bootstrap, then apply Normalize, then apply your custom styles, then any inline styles.

Comment: Yes i know, but is there any way that we can choose which file is gonna change via jquery??